# Convert input language while typing in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field that accepts two languages Arabic and English, what i want is when i type Arabic numbers into this input to convert them into English while the user is typing, i want them to be converted from `['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹']` to `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']`, how can i do that? here is my input code:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Numbers should be converted from Arabic to English here">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `oninput` handler on the input to watch for updates in the text field. Then use a `String#replace` on the input element's value to replace all digits with the one you need.

The replace method can take a function and I used that function In the code below to map the digit directly to the arabic representation by its index in the map array.

```js
let map =  ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

function change(el){
  el.value = el.value.replace(/\d/g, function(match){
    return map[match]
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Numbers should be converted from Arabic to English here" oninput="change(this)">
```

****EDIT****

I'm tripping. OP wanted to go from Arabic to English.
Just change map into an object mapping the arabic representation to the english and then change the regular expression inside replace to capture the arabic instead of digits.

```js
let map =  {
  '۰' : "0", 
  '۱' : "1", 
  '۲' : "2", 
  '۳' : "3", 
  '۴' : "4",
  '۵' : "5", 
  '۶' : "6", 
  '۷' : "7",
  '۸' : "8", 
  '۹' : "9"
 };

function change(el){
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, function(match){
    return map[match]
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Numbers should be converted from Arabic to English here" oninput="change(this)">
```

Comment: I think he meant the other way around. From arabic to english.

Comment: You are correct. I added an edit, but left both ways in.

Answer (score 2):

For Arabic & Persian characters:

```
 let map = {
    "۱": "1",
    "۲": "2",
    "۳": "3",
    "۴": "4",
    "۵": "5",
    "۶": "6",
    "۷": "7",
    "۸": "8",
    "۹": "9",
    "۰": "0",
    "١": "1",
    "٢": "2",
    "٣": "3",
    "٤": "4",
    "٥": "5",
    "٦": "6",
    "٧": "7",
    "٨": "8",
    "٩": "9",
    "٠": "0"
};

function changeToEngNum(el){
    el.value = el.value.replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠]/g, function(match){
        return map[match]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, (I am doing english to arabic btw, you should change the arrays)

Input,

```
<input id="inputTest" type="text" placeholder="Numbers should be converted from Arabic to English here">
```

Javascript,

```
var arabics = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
var engs = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

$("#inputTest").on("keyup", function(e) {
  var insideText = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  var index = engs.indexOf(insideText);
  if (index >= 0) {
    var value = $("#inputTest").val();
    value = value.replace(insideText, arabics[index]);
    $("#inputTest").val(value);
  }

});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z70zjsb6/17/)

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onkeypress` attribute that needs to be given to your .

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Numbers should be converted from Arabic to English here" onkeypress = "convertArabicToNumbers(this)">
```

This attribute will contain a javascript function name, the implementation of this function will be as follows,

Lets say the javascript function is

```
function convertArabicToNumbers(element){
var value = element.value;
// logic to read each character from value variable and and compare it with arabic array and replace each character with number array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for all input that have text type
use jQuery Library

```
var arabics = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
var engs = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];


$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function (e) {

    var insideText = (e.key);
    var index = arabics.indexOf(insideText);
    if (index >= 0) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        value.substr(0, value.length - 1) != null ? value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1) + engs[index] : value = engs[index];
        $(this).val(value);
    }


});
```